ORACLE OCI cloning PDB issues
Basically, I am performing a local clone (to the same CDB) of a very large PDB, approximately 12 terabytes, which is on OCI Oracle 19c, and I used the following command to perform the cloning:
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE PDB_clone FROM PDB identified by CLONE;

However, I encountered some problems. The command has been executing for a few hours, and I don't know how to exactly monitor whether the cloning is actually progressing or not. Additionally, I identified some errors in the CDB alert log, indicating deadlocks. I checked the deadlocks and it seems that none are impacting the execution, but since I don't have ways to monitor the progress, I am not sure. The cloned database is live and always has a high number of transactions. I would like to know if it is recommended to just wait a few more hours to see if the execution finishes, given that the PDB is really large, or if something might be impacting it, as from other experiences it has always been a quick process, but this is the first time I am doing it on such a large database.
I have already tried to check the alert log, validate if the data files are being created, and if a path was created in ASMCMD. I also tried to execute some selects to see if I can monitor the progress:
select count(*) from dba_data_files;

in the source and the cloning database, but the clone only shows 1 data file.
The operation has been running for about 3 hours and managed to create the PDB in mount mode, but so far it hasn't finished and stated "pluggable database created."

Probably better to move the question to dba.stackexchange.com
